# How to below sql query error

Tags: android, sqlite

I using sqllite for my search module.I select multiple status value in sqllite using below code.The error is occured at run time. pls help me.......

Error:

```
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'": , while compiling: select * from issues where  Status IN (CLO,NEW)'
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1118)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1092)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at ez.com.Action_module_screen.setListval1(Action_module_screen.java:1062)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at ez.com.Action_module_screen$4.handleMessage(Action_module_screen.java:695)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
12-10 12:31:56.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(848):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Code:

```
 String sta=Search.status2;
 String doc=Search.document;
 String[] items=sta.split(",");

 String statusFilter = " Status IN (" + items[0];
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(statusFilter);
 for (int j = 1; j < items.length; j++) {
   builder.append(",");
   builder.append(items[j]);
 }
 builder.append(')');

  Cursor dbcur = myDB.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where " + builder.toString() + "'", null);
  if(dbcur.moveToFirst())
     {
      int k=0;
      System.out.println("enter first");
        do
         {
      String title1=dbcur.getString(dbcur.getColumnIndex("Title"));
      System.out.println("title"+title1);
      String name1=dbcur.getString(dbcur.getColumnIndex("Name"));
      System.out.println("name"+name1);
      String open1=dbcur.getString(dbcur.getColumnIndex("Open"));
      System.out.println("open"+open1);
      String close1=dbcur.getString(dbcur.getColumnIndex("Close"));
      System.out.println("close"+close1);
      String no1=dbcur.getString(dbcur.getColumnIndex("No"));
      System.out.println("no"+no1);
      no.add(no1+","+k);
   first.put(no1+","+k, title1);
   second.put(no1+","+k,name1);
   third.put(no1+","+k, open1);
   fourth.put(no1+","+k,close1);
   k=k+1; 
   mylist=sorting(no,1,true); 
        }while(dbcur.moveToNext());
          }
     dbcur.close();
  myDB.close();
```

Comment: I've added notes on your second problem to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It couldn't be more obvious, can it?

`SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'": , while compiling: select * from issues where  Status IN (CLO,NEW)'`

That single quote at the end is a SQL syntax error.

Comment: I have to change below error occured.......12-10 12:47:47.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1460): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: NEW: , while compiling: select * from issues where  Status IN (CLO,NEW)
12-10 12:47:47.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)

Comment: @user533787: I knew you were going to say this. Why are you assembling a raw query if you don't even know SQL?? Too little knowledge in SQL will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Concerning your problem: 'CLO' and 'NEW' obviously must be written as strings, e.g. `WHERE status IN ('CLO', 'NEW')`. Martin Clayton has a solution in his answer, but you shouldn't copy-paste code unless you understand it!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error at the following line:

```
  Cursor dbcur = myDB.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where " + builder.toString() + "'", null);
```

Remove `+ "'"`
 after the builder.toString().

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Comment: I have change but below error occred...................................12-10 12:47:47.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1460): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: NEW: , while compiling: select * from issues where  Status IN (CLO,NEW)
12-10 12:47:47.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1460):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)

Comment: can you prepare a string variable of your query and output it in the log. There seems to be some problem with the final query which is prepared dynamically.. Just paste the result of the string variable here from the logcat..